# How to reduce clique to Hamiltonian cycle in an undirected graph?

Tags: algorithms

Recently, I studied how to prove a problem is NP-complete. From the book [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (CLRS, 3rd edition), there is an example of reducing vertex cover to Hamiltonian cycle. I believe that it is possible to directly reduce clique to Hamiltonian cycle in an undirected graph, but how to convert it in polynomial time?

[Deleted question]

Comment: Please do not delete and reask a question when you have received a (partially) useful answer.

Comment: @Discretelizard No, the answer is correct only if the graph is directed.

Comment: @Discretelizard I request for undeleting the question I posted, or delete the answer of this question.

Comment: @Discretelizard He just gave an answer and left, but my problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: @Discretelizard I quit.

Comment: Please be aware that most people react to posts and comments within the span of a few days. So, if nothing has happened after a few hours, this often doesn't mean they have given up on you, but simply that they haven't seen your comment yet.

Comment: @HongyuShen Is there some difficulty in taking a CLIQUE instance and reducing it to VERTEX COVER, and then applying the reduction from VERTEX COVER to HAMCYCLE?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce clique to SAT (Cook's theorem).  You can reduce SAT to Hamiltonian cycle (see e.g. [Easy reduction from 3SAT to Hamiltonian path problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/222/755) for the main ideas).  Compose these two, and you get a reduction from clique to Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: How to solve it if the graph is undirected?

Comment: You cannot always assume it is directed by default(the easiest case).